# How can I split a list into smaller lists?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

I have a list:

```
lists = (['1','2','3','S','3','4','S','4','6','7'])
```

And I want to split the list into s smaller list everytime 'S' appears and eliminate 'S' into something like:

```
([['1','2','3'],['3','4],['4','6','7']])
```

My code:

```
def x (lists):
    empty = ''
    list = []

    for x in lists:
        if x == empty:
            list[-1:].append(x)
        else:
            list.append([x])

    return (list)
```

I tried something like this, but I am quite new to python, and Im getting nowhere. Nothing fancy please, how would I fix what I have?

Answer (score 5):

Try [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lists = ['1','2','3','S','3','4','S','4','6','7']
>>> [list(g[1]) for g in groupby(lists, lambda i:i!='S') if g[0]]
[['1', '2', '3'], ['3', '4'], ['4', '6', '7']]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help! This answer works, however, Is there anyway of fixing what I have? I dont think I am that far off, and I would rather stick with what I understand for now, since I am quite new!

Comment: `groupby()` is the key-point here. You may need to read python doc.

Comment: @user1828072 The problem with 'fixing what you already have' is that your approach is . . . well, not particularly pythonic. That's not to say (the end result of) your approach isn't right, just less preferable, and probably less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like `map(list,''.join(lists).split('S'))`

Alternately, `[list(s) for s in ''.join(lists).split('S'))`

Answer (score 1):

Well, may be funny, but this should work:

```
[s.split('#') for s in '#'.join(lists).split('#S#')]
```

Instead of the `'#'` any character can be used if it's unlikely to appear in `lists`.